# Hive sql expand multiple columns to rows

Tags: sql, hive

I have a hive table which has the following format：

```
user | item | like | comment
 Joe     5      1       0
 Lan     3      0       1
Mack     5      1       1
```

and I want use HIVE SQL to convert like and comment to the user behavior column, then keep rows which user and item and times of behaviors：

```
user | item | behavior | times
 Joe     5      like       1
 Joe     5      comment    0
 Lan     3      like       0
 Lan     3      comment    1
 Mack    5      like       1
 Mack    5      comment    1
```

could you please give any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Using `map` and `explode`.

```
select user,item,behavior,times
from tbl 
lateral view explode(map('like',like,'comment',comment)) t as behavior,times
```

As as side note, you should avoid using reserved keywords like `user`, `like`, `comment` as column names.

Comment: Thanks. This looks elegant and concise. I would like to learn about lateral view and explode.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by Prabhala and Linoff. Here I'm offering yet another way, the builtin UDTF `stack`, which is both intuitive and native.

```sql
select
    stack(2, user, item, 'like',    like,
             user, item, 'comment', comment)
         as (user, item, behavior, times)
from tbl
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select user, item, 'like' as behavior, like as times
from t
union all
select user, item, 'comment' as behavior, comment as times
from t;
```